# Access order_by foreign model field in Django ResultSet

Tags: django

So imagine you're doing something like

```
books = Book.objects.all().order_by('shopsales__qty')
```

Where `shopsales` is a reference to the `ShopSales` model which stores sales of a certain book by a certain shop and so has a `ForeignKey` field back to the `Book` model and a `qty` field.

Now the above will fetch all books from your books table ordered by a field from a different table. To do so, the generated SQL will have a join and will add a `shopsales__qty` field to the `SELECT` fields list alongside all fields from the Book model itself. However, if you then go through your returned books, it appears the the foreign field used for ordering has been discarded.. (even though it has been selected.. for the sake of the ordering).

Is there any way to have that field kept in the returned `Book` objects?

Comment: sorry about the too simplified structure in the first version of the question - I am aware of select_related() but in my case it's actually sadly not appropriate.

Comment: So no other suggestions other than using `values()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [value()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values)

```
books = Book.objects.all().order_by('publisher__revenue').value('title','publisher__revenue')
```

If you need more attributes, you can add them to `value()`

Comment: Thanks, I can imagine that this will work, but I'm afraid I have more select_related() calls on the QuerySet which I don't really want to substitute with explicit field names if possible..